# AngularJS- why am I needing $scope.$apply within $scope.$on?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have some code that is not behaving as expected...  I have an event listener within a AngularJS controller like this:

```
$scope.$on("newClipSelected", function(e) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.isReady = true;
    });
});
```

The controller's markup has a ng-show='isReady'.  When this event handler runs, the ng-show region shows as expected.  However, this event handler does not work:

```
$scope.$on("newClipSelected", function(e) {
    $scope.isReady = true;
});
```

With this event handler, if I use the debugger to expect the AngularJS scope I do see that  $scope.isReady=true, however the ng-show element is not showing.

Its my understanding that $scope.$on will in fact call $watch/$apply as appropriate.  So why am I needing to call $apply in this case?

The event is being triggered by a call to $rootScope.$broadcast() within a non-angularJS asynchronous completion event.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, angular doesn't fire `$apply` on the events so if `$broadcast` is called outside angular's context, you are going to need to `$apply` by hand.

Check the source [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js)

Comment: And in this case the `$scope.$apply` should be put around the non-Angular code that is broadcasting the event (not the event listener) so that only one digest cycle is performed.

Comment: Thank you.  I wanted to link a forum thread where I expanded on my scenario a bit: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/angular/xaZcuKB7IlA/discussion.  I believe your answer is correct but I am unsure about which $scope I should $apply when doing the broadcast (as discussed in the forum post).

Answer (score 2):

`$on` and `$broadcast` doesn't call `$apply` for you, you need to call it yourself. I'm not sure why that is, but my guess is that it's because a digest is a bit expensive, and it would be a cost to run a digest cycle for every event.