# DropDown doesn't close on click out

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have a problem, if you see the [**Plunker link**](http://embed.plnkr.co/GzueezzHpWhbjMAlrmWC/preview), i don't know how to make my drop down close automatically when i click out the directive.

can anybody give suggestions to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: You could use a directive to listen on the window, if a click happened broadcast an event (e.g. "dropdown:close", which gets listened to on your dropdownDirective. The dropdownDirective should then just call your function which toggles the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution according to my comment:

http://plnkr.co/edit/2UG1Kj2l3fuVgYXaOB6d?p=preview

I have a custom directive sitting on the body

```
<body class="container" ng-controller="mainCtrl" dropdown-listener>
```

which listens on the window for click events.

It fires an event which your dropdownDirective is listening to:

```
myApp.directive('dropdownListener', function ($window, $rootScope) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',

        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
          var w = angular.element($window);

          w.bind('click', function(){
            $rootScope.$broadcast('dropdown:close');
          });
                }
            }
        });
```

In your `dropdownDirective`

```
$scope.$on('dropdown:close', function (event, data) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      if($scope.open) { //only close when it is open
        $scope.open = !$scope.open; //quick and dirty solution - withouth apply it didn't work. Maybe you could investigate further
      }
      });
  })
```

Comment: I understand, 
but why applying this code, (on you plunker link), i can't select element that are inside the dropdown?, click over the elements ?. thanks

Comment: Then just use `$event.stopPropagation()` as seen in LoC 8 in your dropdownView.html `<a class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle ng-click='openDropdown(); $event.stopPropagation()'>Select...</a>` on the functions, to disable bubbling up the event to the dropdDownListener.

Comment: Updated the plnkr accordingly. Uses now the $event.stopPropgation on all dropdown functions.

Comment: I think that i was wrong, when i click over CheckAll or UncheckAll i see tha second time that i open the dropdown, that the style changed. But if you remember on my first plunker: (http://embed.plnkr.co/GzueezzHpWhbjMAlrmWC/preview) i could check over that elements, and the drop down doesn't close. My problem was, how i colud stay doing click inside the dropdown, and how i close it just, when i click out the dropdown.  Thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414017/angularjs-why-am-i-needing-scope-apply-within-scope-on for $apply question.

Comment: Please reload the plnkr. I guess it is now working exactly how you want it to behave. Clicking inside the dropdown is not closing it. Click outside the dropdown is closing it (if it is open - otherwise does nothing).

Comment: Now ... is ok
You are right men.

Really THANKS for your help.

Comment: thanks again ... i dont wanna bother. But please can you help me again with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723837/insert-a-small-form-on-my-dropdown-directive ... thanks