# Insert a small form into a dropDown directive

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I need help with this **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/j6MseyR6TUablskf6pQV?p=preview)**

On my job i need open a small dropdown, that will contain a small form. It must be a directive.

1- My directive will receive a model (something that i don't know why, it doent's show)

2- the model must be printed on the input

3- with the save button the new paremeter writen must pass by a callback to the paren

4. if i click out the dropdown or if i click cancel button, the dropdown must close.

can any body help me with this job?

Really thanks

```
<body class="container" ng-controller="mainCtrl" dropdown-listener>

  <h1>option DropDown</h1>

  original data: <h4>{{profile.city}},{{profile.province}},{{profile.country}}</h4>

  <dropdown-multiselect user-profile="profile"></dropdown-multiselect>

</body>
```

Comment: What is the specific problem? You have stated what you are trying to do but not what problems you are having doing it

Comment: if you see the plunk link, and see the point that i write up, you will se that since point 1 to 4, are the point that doesn't work. I don't know what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have something that is close to what you are looking for.

The first thing you need is the auto-close set to disabled on your dropdown so it doesn't close as soon as you click on it.

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown auto-close="disabled" is-open="isopen">
```

You also had a problem where you were trying to directly link the form inputs to the outer variables.  I presume you only want to set those when "submit" is pressed?

Anyways... have a look at this plunker and see if it's closer to what you're looking for.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rK3gmN9rHksZrGuEM6r6?p=preview

Edited the plunker to now have initial values using ng-init.

```
<input type="text" id="ciudad" ng-init="profile.country=initProfile.country" ng-model="profile.country"></input>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's really close. But i don't understad why it doesn't receive the first value from the main Controller, y see that you delete the parameter "=" on the directive... Why?  Regards

Comment: The reason it wasn't taking the value from the main controller was that you had ".value" at the end of the ng-model.

Comment: Edited the plunker to give initial values using ng-init.  You could tie them directly using ng-model as you did before.  Just remove the .value you had in your example plunker.

Comment: if you click on my first plunker (i update it)
i have the next error from the console:  RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Scope.$scope.sendBackParams (dropdownDirective.js:30)
    at Scope.$scope.sendBackParams (dropdownDirective.js:30) can you see it?

Comment: With the last modification over your plunker, i can see that you resolve that.  You don't have an idea how much i was traying to resolve that. Really thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could help! :)

Comment: Hello ... DWDuck, again. I found a bug into your script (i'm trying to solve too) but, did you see that when you open the dropdown, and write something on any input and and you DON'T do click over submit.... you click over CANCEL. And if you open the dropdown again, how you didn't submit anything, the values must be the same value from the ng-init.  Did you understand the bug?. If you have time just, can you see it too?  Regards

Comment: here is the corrected version: http://embed.plnkr.co/kxVNgILUJoitbyIQq6LN/preview - I get it

Comment: Glad you figured it out Julio... sorry I couldn't help I was out for a while.

Comment: can you give a hand with this ? -->

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31748042/dropdown-inside-to-other-dropdown-directive-doesnt-open . I had a drop down that doesn't open ... Thanks